# AngularJS: don't show part of string if value is empty in repeater

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat in a select menu:

```
<label>Country</label>
    <select name="seller-country" class="form-control input-sm">
      <option ng-repeat="c in countries | orderBy:predicate" value="{{c.code}}">{{c.code}} ({{c.name}}) </option>
    </select>
```

The first item in the data is empty, as in

```
{
  "countries": [{
     "name": "",
     "code": ""
     }, ...
```

I set up the binding above so the menu items will read as in `CA (Canada)`, so for the empty string it reads `()`.  I'd like to not show the parens for the empty string.

**UPDATE**
The answer below is indeed correct, but in this case I was the one who added the empty first item in a misguided attempt to get an empty select item before checking the Angular docs for select.  It seems you can do exactly what I was trying to do by simply adding an extra first `option` item:

```
<select name="seller-country" class="form-control input-sm">
      <option value="">Choose...</option>
      <option ng-repeat="c in countries | orderBy:predicate" value="{{c.code}}">{{c.code}} ({{c.name}}) </option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <option ng-repeat="c in countries | orderBy:predicate"
     ng-if="c.code != '' && c.name!= '' && c.code != null && c.name!= null" 
     value="{{c.code}}">{{c.code}} ({{c.name}}) </option>
```